# How many edges could the resulting polygon(s) of unionizing $n$ triangles have in maximum?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

How many edges could the resulting polygon(s) created by unionizing $n$ triangles have in maximum?

Here unionizing means taking the union of the interiors, examples are attached below. I'm not sure if this means the same as "union in sets". Note that the result could result in multiple polygons and even non-convex polygons.

It seems like a constructive problem. Obviously it's 12 for $n=2$ (the figure on the flag of Israel) but I can't find the solution for any bigger $n$ even $n=3$. If anyone knows the solution please share it with me.
[image: here]

Comment: Please add your question to the body of your post.

Comment: This is very unclear, what do you mean by unionizing? Does your "union" work like a triangulation of the polygon you created? Does it have to be convex? Because if you have to glue triangles on edges, this is restrictive. But if it is just the union as sets you will have various sets

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math3.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: I don't know what happens when you "unionize" a collection of triangles, other than that you have to pay them more.

Comment: Unionizing here means taking the union of the interiors.

Comment: Sorry, my 1st link should have been https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391

Comment: Could you explain why it's $12$ for $n=2$? The top-right polygon in your figure seems to have the maximal edges, and I can only see $6$ edges. Also, by "in maximum", do you mean you want to identify what is the maximum number of edges a polygon created by your process could have?

Comment: We could get 12 by putting the triangles together in the way the flag of Israel did. And yes, I would like to identify the maximum number of edges the polygon(s) could have.